# Proving that a proposition is a tautology

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I did it but I am not sure that I solved it in the right way...

[I tried to solve that $((p \lor q) \land (\lnot p \lor r)) \to (q \lor r)$]

[image]

Comment: When you have $((p \wedge \neg r) \vee r) \vee q$ inbetween lines 8 and 9, you should be careful about just dropping parentheses. The $\vee$ operation distributes over parentheses (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic), so you should have something like $((p \vee r) \wedge (\neg r \vee r)) \vee q$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost good: you need to keep parenthesis in the line "DeMorgan's laws" because in general $(A \land B) \lor C \neq A \land (B \lor C)$ (for example when $A=B=0, C=1$), so the last five lines are not valid.

Two faster ways to do the exercise:

- if $P=0$ then the proposition becomes $Q \Rightarrow Q \lor R$ which is true; if $P=1$ then the proposition becomes $R \Rightarrow Q \lor R$ which is true again, so the original proposition is true;
- use the implication rule for the outer implication to obtain 
  $$(\lnot[(p \lor q) \land (\lnot p \lor r)])\lor(q \lor r)$$
  $$[\lnot p \land \lnot q] \lor [p \land \lnot r] \lor q \lor r$$
  Now notice that $(A \land \lnot B) \lor B = A \lor B$, so we obtain
  $$([\lnot p \land \lnot q] \lor q) \lor([p \land \lnot r] \lor r)$$
  $$\lnot p \lor  q \lor p \lor r$$